# How to show different components for different URLs?

Tags: reactjs, url

So if the page URL is just a `/`, I want to render the `HomeNavbar` component. If it isn't, then I simply want `BackNavbar`. I tried doing the ff.:

```
{window.location.pathname === '/' ? <HomeNavbar /> : <BackNavbar />}
```

This doesn't work unless I reload to get it working. So I tried using `useEffect` hook like this to always check if pathname is / and render the correct component:

```
const App = () => {
  const navbar = () => {
    if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
        return <HomeNavbar />;
    } else {
        return <BackNavbar />;
    }};

  useEffect(() => {
    navbar();
  }, []);

return (
    <div className='App'>
        {navbar()}
    </div>
)
```

But this doesn't work. Why? Please help.

Comment: Are you using class or function to create your components? Provide more info.

Comment: My components are functional.

Comment: @Mrjadeja please see updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you don't have to use `useEffect()` at all because you just call `navbar()` in your jsx which runs everytime your component mount or render.

**Solution**

```
// index.js file
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

//... some codes
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Now you can access props in your app component.

> **Note:** *i'm using this approach because it make easy to work with `history` in react instead of `windows.location`*

there are 2 approaches to access history in App component

**1 withRouter**

```
// App.js file
import { withrouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = (props) => {
  const navbar = () => {
    if (props.history.location.pathname === '/') {
        return <HomeNavbar />;
    } else {
        return <BackNavbar />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
        {navbar()}
    </div>
  )
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

**2 useHistory hook**

```
// App.js file
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const navbar = () => {
    if (history.location.pathname === '/') {
        return <HomeNavbar />;
    } else {
        return <BackNavbar />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
        {navbar()}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

if your routes wrapped like below you can access `props` in any route.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Router exact path='/path/for/component' component={YourComponent} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

or if your component does not comes from `<Route />` you can use `withRouter` higher order component to wrap your componet and now you can access props.

> i prefer `withRouter` beacause it gives you more to work with rather than `useHistory` hook because it just gives you history.

if using **method 1**, `console.log(props)` or if using **method 2**, `console.log(history)` can gives you everything you can experiment with.

> you must check out this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiaFedx5cfA&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9ij8CfkAY2RAGb-tmkNwQHG&index=27) or you can [browse full
> playlist](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9ij8CfkAY2RAGb-tmkNwQHG) by `TheNetNinja`.

**Happy Programming :)**

Comment: I first tried using the useHistory hook but it doesn't seem to work. But then I tried withRouter and it works! Thanks a lot @Mrjadeja and thanks for the references.

Comment: If you need help in react let me know. view my profile for contact :)

Comment: Hello @Mrjadeja I need your help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67017792/how-to-create-a-history-log-in-react